# Find QWidget of single instance Qt application

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm trying to create a single instance Qt application and I'm at the point this works, but now I want to focus the already started instance when a second is started.
QWidget::find(g_hWnd) should return the widget but it fails and crashes on w->show();

Any thoughts?

```
#pragma data_seg("Shared")
HWND g_hWnd = NULL;
#pragma data_seg()
#pragma comment(linker,"/section:Shared,rws")

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (g_hWnd)
    {
        QWidget* w = QWidget::find(g_hWnd);
        w->show();
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        mainWindow w;
        w.show();
        g_hWnd = a.topLevelWidgets().at(0)->winId(); //or w.winId()?

        return a.exec();
    }
}
```

**edit: I now see Trolltech released the [QtSingleApplication](http://doc.trolltech.com/solutions/4/qtsingleapplication/qtsingleapplication.html) class under LGPL.**

Comment: Have you tried debugging both at the same time to determine the g_hWnd in the second application matches the first?

Comment: They don't match, but still it detects there's already a instance running.

Comment: It's weird, sometimes one of the g_hWnd variables value is 0 and other times they match each other, but it still crashes on the find and focus of the qwidget.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the [qtsingleapplication](http://doc.trolltech.com/solutions/4/qtsingleapplication/qtsingleapplication.html) API

edit- It's a separate download  [see here](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4/Utilities/qtsingleapplication/) for both LGPL and Commercial editions

Comment: QtSingleApplication isn't part of any version of Qt. It's an unsupported add-on they make available out of the goodness of their hearts. You can find it here: http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4/Utilities/qtsingleapplication/

Comment: Oh wow, last time I checked it was only available for the commercial edition. I love Trolltech!

Comment: corne, can you update your question to reflect the QtSingleApplication statement? Thanks.

Comment: The new location for QtSingleApplication is http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/qt-solutions/trees/master/qtsingleapplication

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QSharedMemory>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
     MainWindow w;

    QSharedMemory shared("61BB200D-3579-453e-9044-");
    if(shared.create(512,QSharedMemory::ReadWrite)==true)
    {
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setText("I am first.");
        msgBox.exec();
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setText("i am already running.");
        msgBox.exec();
        exit(0);
    }
    //shared.AlreadyExists()

    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be the problem you're having:

> WId QWidget::winId () const
>
> Returns the window system identifier
>   of the widget.
>
> Portable in principle, but if you use
>   it you are probably about to do
>   something non-portable. Be careful.
>
> If a widget is non-native (alien) and
>   winId() is invoked on it, that widget
>   will be provided a native handle.
>
> **Note: We recommend that you do not
>   store this value as it is likely to
>   change at run-time.**

[Source](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qwidget.html#winId)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your method is going to work.

The best approach is still by running a local server (see [QLocalServer](http://doc.trolltech.com/qlocalserver.html)) that listens from a specific socket. An newly launched instance will detect the running server and can pipe agreed command to e.g. set the focus, open a new file, etc.

A similar approach is to use named shared memory (see [QSharedMemory](http://doc.trolltech.com/qsharedmemory.html)). Same like before, if the shared memory exists already, the other side can control it by sending suitable commands.