# Disable running multiple instances of application (installed using Inno Setup installer) from Start menu

Tags: icons, inno-setup

In my installation, I've included a shortcut icon. However, using this shortcut icon allows me to launch numerous instances of my process, which is unwanted.

Only one copy of my installer should be operating at any given time. How can I ensure that there is only one instance or process of the installer running? The installer should either quietly ignore repeated clicks on the shortcut icon or display a notification.
Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

```
[Run]
Filename: MyProg.exe Flags: skipifsilent nowait;

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\MyProg"; Filename: "MyProg.exe"; IconFilename: "app.ico" 
Name: "{userdesktop}\MyProg"; Filename: "MyProg.exe"; IconFilename: "app.ico"
```

The creation of multiple instances of MyProg.exe upon clicking the desktop icon is undesired.

Answer (score 0):

Your icon runs your application (`MyProg.exe`), not the installer. The installer has nothing to do with this. It's your application that needs to prevent repeated runs.

The standard way of preventing multiple instances of a Windows application is to create a named mutex by the application, see [Use Win API to determine if an instance of an executable is already running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18184019/850848#18184226).