# How QReadWriteLock works properly

Tags: qt

I had a server programm that takes `settings` from a file. I tried to lock while reading it using `QReadWriteLock` class allocated dynamically in my own class and released to free store in destructor of my class object of which exists in `main()`. My major was to lock it, so that if launched, the second time .exe of the programm it couldn't get access so that I could have had a `Singleapplication` Compiling shows no error but when I launch my server from second .exe (yet the first functioning) it also has a access to settings. What is my mistake or I'm not suppose to utilize QReadWriteLock in this case, due to it's related to threads only? Not to seperate executables?

Comment: you read settings from QFile or QSettings ? and Yes QReadWriteLock works in side single executable. May be you can open setting file with  Write mode, that should prevent other executable from opening setting in write mode again.

Answer (score 0):

The [QReadWriteLock](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qreadwritelock.html) is used to synchronize producer/consumer-like threads within a single application. If you want to prevent starting the same executable more than once, you'd use a PID-file or something alike. An other option is to use the QtSingleApplication code from the QtSolutions-plugin: [Qt: Best practice for a single instance app protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006547/qt-best-practice-for-a-single-instance-app-protection).