# How to manage single instance of a Qt app on crash?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to execute my application as single instance,  currently I am using  `QSharedMemory` and working fine. I am using Qt5.2.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Below is my test code:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
a.processEvents();

const char* MEM_KEY = "56";
QSharedMemory sharedMem(MEM_KEY);

if( !sharedMem.create( 512, QSharedMemory::ReadWrite) )
{
  QMessageBox msgBox;
  msgBox.setText( QObject::tr("Can't start more than one instance of the application.") );
  msgBox.setIcon( QMessageBox::Critical );
  msgBox.exec();
  exit(0);
}


MainWindow w;
w.show();

int p=0;
//p=p/0; // create exception here

return a.exec();
```

But the `if` makes the application crash(as shown in above code). If I start the application again, it shows `Can't start more than one instance of the application`, which means the previous instance is still there even if it has crashed. It should not happen in my case.

How can I restart my application in such a situation?

**Edit:**

Actually my original project contains lot of source files (the above one just made for testing). I want to implement it on my original project with editing least source file, if possible only by editing main.cpp

Comment: what happen if you try/catch you crash, in catch unlock the shared memory then exit the app?

Comment: Ok, It might be possible, but in my case my original project contains many source file(the above one just made for testing), I want  to implement it on my original project with editing least source file, if possible only by editing main.cpp

Comment: What does `QSharedMemory::error()` returns after `sharedMem.create` failed? *Off-topic* - you can use static function `QMessageBox::critical(...)` instead of 4 lines you used

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, QSharedMemory::error() returns 4 on both crash and instance exist(previous app running normally) there.

Comment: I Got it working by using  the solution [here][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006547/qt-best-practice-for-a-single-instance-app-protection/28172162#28172162

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a QSetting:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QSettings settings;
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    if(!settings.exitedNormaly()) {
        // In case of crash
    }

    // set the flag to false
    settings.setExitedNormaly(false);

    MainWindow w(&settings);
    w.processArg(argc, argv);
    w.show();

    int result = a.exec();
    settings.setExitedNormaly(result == 0);

    return result;
}
```

Combined with your shared memory, you'll be able to unlock the block in case of application crash.

Comment: Hi, suppose the application is running and the user start the application again, then how can I mange with above solution, means setExitedNormaly still false.

Comment: @Haris I don't really know... Maybe with a second setting storing the number of opened instance ?

Answer (score 1):

for linux:

//----------------------------------

```
QProcess *m_prSystemCall;
m_prSystemCall = new QProcess();

QString Commnd = "pgrep  " + qApp->applicationDisplayName();
m_prSystemCall->start(Commnd);
m_prSystemCall->waitForFinished(8000);
QString output(m_prSystemCall->readAllStandardOutput());
QStringList AppList = output.split("\n", QString::SkipEmptyParts);
qDebug() <<"pgrep out:"<<AppList;
for(int i=0;i<AppList.size()-1;i++)
{
    Commnd = "kill " + AppList.at(i);
    m_prSystemCall->start(Commnd);
    m_prSystemCall->waitForFinished(8000);
}
```

//-------------------------------------------------------

and for Windows:

```
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <comdef.h>

QString pName = qApp->applicationDisplayName();
pName += ".exe";
PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
{
    DWORD myPID =  GetCurrentProcessId();
    while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        const WCHAR* wc = entry.szExeFile ;
        _bstr_t b(wc);
        const char* c = b;

        if (stricmp(c, pName.toStdString().c_str()) == 0)
        {
            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);

            qDebug() <<"myPID: "<< myPID << "entry.th32ProcessID" << entry.th32ProcessID;
            if(myPID != entry.th32ProcessID)
                TerminateProcess(hProcess,0);
            QThread::msleep(10);
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }
    }

}

CloseHandle(snapshot);
```